# Error- Procedure or function 'hrm_Langauges' expects parameter '@CreatedOn', which was not supplied

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview, stored-procedures

I am trying to delete record from grid but getting this error.

Don't know why getting this error.

Here is my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[hrm_Langauges]
(
    @Name varchar(120),
    @CreatedOn datetime,
    @UpdatedOn datetime,
    @CreatedBy bigint=0,
    @UpdatedBy bigint=0,
    @IsDeleted bit=0,
    @status as varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @ID int;
        SELECT @ID = coalesce((select max(ID) + 1 from Languages), 1)
    COMMIT   

    if(@status = 'Display')
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Languages];
    END
    else if(@status = 'Add')
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT Name FROM [dbo].[Languages] WHERE Name = @Name)
    Begin
    Return 0
    End
    Else
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Languages](Name,CreatedOn,CreatedBy) VALUES(@Name,@CreatedOn,@CreatedBy)
    END
    else if(@status = 'Update')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[Languages] Set Name=@Name,UpdatedOn=@UpdatedOn WHERE ID=@ID
    END
    else if(@status = 'Delete')
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM [dbo].[Languages] WHERE NAME=@NAME
    END
END
```

**Here is my code for delete record**

```
string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
SqlCommand command;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tblAdd.Visible = false;
    Label1.Visible = false;
    //GridView1.DataBind();
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            fillLanguageGrid();
        }
}

public void fillLanguageGrid()
    {   
        GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
        GridView1.DataBind(); 
    }

protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkdelete = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chk");
        if (chkdelete.Checked)
        {
            string name= Convert.ToString(GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Values["Name"].ToString());
           // command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
            deleteRecordByName(name);
        }
    }
    fillLanguageGrid();
}

public void deleteRecordByName(string Name)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[hrm_Langauges]", sqlConnection))
    {
        //  define this to be a stored procedure
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
        // define the parameter and set its value
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = Name;
        command.Parameters["@status"].Value = "Delete";
        //open connection, execute DELETE query, close connection
        sqlConnection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Can anyone suggest either my sp is not correct or my asp.net code.

While executing code I am getting error:

> Procedure or function 'hrm_Langauges' expects parameter '@CreatedOn', which was not supplied.

Comment: **READ the error message!** Then look at your stored procedure - it expects a parameter `@CreatedOn DATETIME`. Look at your C# code calling it - does it create a `SqlParameter` for `@CreatedOn` and supply a value for it??????

Comment: For deleting record no need to pass that parameter.

Comment: If it's defined on the stored procedure list of parameters - then it **must be supplied**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass default value for each Parameters.

Change your code

from

```
 @Name varchar(120),
@CreatedOn datetime,
@UpdatedOn datetime,
@CreatedBy bigint=0,
@UpdatedBy bigint=0,
@IsDeleted bit=0,
@status as varchar(50)
```

to

```
@Name varchar(120),
@CreatedOn datetime=0,
@UpdatedOn datetime=0,
@CreatedBy bigint=0,
@UpdatedBy bigint=0,
@IsDeleted bit=0,
@status as varchar(50)
```